# Add a Horizontal Spinbox/Selection Box in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is there a way to make a Horizontal Spinbox/Selection Box in Tkinter in Python i.e. with arrows being in left and right directions and Text to be selected is in between those arrows.
The hypothetical image is attached below.

[Image of Required Horizontal Selection Box / Spinbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LtLK.jpg)

Comment: No, that's not a builtin widget or a standard ttk widget. But you can make anything you want, and that does not seem hard to make. Just a Label with a couple of Buttons on the ends.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]